# Why is the drawer basket tilted in my refrigerator?

Tags: appliances, freezer

I have a Whirlpool gold fridge/freezer. I had to remove the drawer to defrost. When putting it back in, I noticed that the drawer seems to go in at an angle. Putting it back this way the drawer and door seems to shut snugly. But I would have expected the drawer to stay level. Is intended to go in at an angle?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Was it tilted before you took it out?  Quite a few drawers go in tilted/at an angle before fitting in level.  Sometimes it is tricky to fit right if you miss the right spot.

Comment: Try turning the basket around and placing it in the slots properly.

Comment: You've put the basket back in backwards. The flat side goes towards the door in front, and the angled side goes at the back.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

That basket is meant to sit completely in the lower slotted ridge and flat. Try adjusting it to fit down in there. You might have a basket in backwards,  so try switching it around.

Comment: I'd say 99% chance the basket is backwards, because the angled side is towards the vertical door, which makes no sense. But the inside back of the refrigerator is very likely to be angled.

Comment: the basket was in backwards. I turned it around and it went right in. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4):

I am betting bar is meant to ride on shelf behind the raised tabs.  I colored bar red and shelf green.

[image: pic]

That would give the bar support along its entire length which is sensible.  Tabs keep bar from falling off the shelf.

Maybe there is a similar setup in the level shelf one up.  You can see if that one also has a shelf with little tabs and how that shelf is supported.

Comment: There is a ridge in front that the basket needs to slide under, but is sitting on top of.

Answer (score 0):

If it's not in backwards, any chance the edge of the basket is meant to sit on the upper edge, as shown in the attached picture?

[image]